# jQuery tab losing focus

Tags: php, jquery

I am using following jQuery code to toggle between the tabs on a page:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#questions > div').hide();
    jQuery('#questions  div:first').show();
    jQuery('#questions  ul li:first').addClass('active');

    jQuery('#questions  ul li a').click(function(){
        jQuery('#questions  ul li').removeClass('active');
        jQuery('#questions  ul li').removeClass('selected');
        jQuery(this).parent().addClass('active');
        jQuery(this).parent().addClass('selected');
        var currentTab = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        jQuery('#questions > div').hide();
        jQuery(currentTab).show();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Now problem is under one of the tabs i have a delete line call:

```
<div id ="questions">
  <ul>
    <li class="selected"><a href="#tab-1"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-2"></a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id ="tab-1">
    <ul>
       <li class="links delete">
         <a href="#" onclick="deleteQuestion(<?php print($question_row; ?>); return false;"  
                  class="links">Delete</a> 
       </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Now when user tries to delete the link tab loses its focus and nothing gets shown under the tab. 
Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do when you call `jQuery(currentTab).show()`?

Comment: Se what this code is doing. Tab-1 is selected at first. Than when user clicks on Tab-2 it shifts the focus to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#questions > div').hide();
        jQuery('#questions > div:first').show();
        jQuery('#questions > ul li:first').addClass('active');

        jQuery('#questions > ul > li > a').click(function(){
            jQuery('#questions > ul > li').removeClass('active');
            jQuery('#questions > ul > li').removeClass('selected');
            jQuery(this).parent().addClass('active');
            jQuery(this).parent().addClass('selected');
            var currentTab = jQuery(this).attr('href');
            jQuery('#questions > div').hide();
            jQuery(currentTab).show();
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: its not working. i think i forgot to add tabs links so you did not get the right code. Can you please look again?